# Broken Wireless Mouse

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse

I have a elecom M-BL21DB 2.4GHz wireless mouse. Everything was good, my mouse work perfectly but one day it just stop working. The LED is still working, my laptop can still recognize the mouse but the the cursor and the button stopped working, even with the dpi button. When i press the dpi button there supposed to be red led next to the button but nothing is happening. I tried different computer but it's still the same. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried changing the batteries?

Comment: Yes i have changed the batteries many times and still no hope. But thanks for the suggestion.